# How to remove the check box in the lists

Tags: angular, angular-material

I got this 
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples?file=app%2Fselection-list%2Fselection-list.component.html) example for lists with selection as shown in below image.

[image]

In the selection list,the list is selecting fine but how can i remove the checkbox?

Comment: which check box you want to remove?

Comment: can you please describe in brief what you exactly try to doing or what is your requirement?

Comment: In selection lists example.as shown in the image.

Comment: so you want to remove check box which is not selected?

Comment: As shown in the image there is a list with selection,the working stackblitz example i have given.I don't want the selected option(right mark with check box) as shown in the image.@KaushikAndani

Comment: I don't want checkbox at all,weather its selected/or not. If it is selected it's just change the background color.I don't want any check box.@UnluckyAj

Comment: I think he wanted to toggle between the states of having the checkboxes and not having the checkboxes...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add `display:none` for this

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-remove-the-check-box-in-the-lists?file=app/selection-list/selection-list.component.css)**

> .css /.sccc

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep.mat-pseudo-checkbox{
      display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This one just will remove the checkbox but the selection wont work well then you need to make more customization.

Answer (score 2):

Ng-deep is deprecated. Alternatively use: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-name',
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

CSS

```
component-name .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use hideSingleSelectionIndicator in mat-selection-list like this:
<mat-selection-list [multiple]="false" hideSingleSelectionIndicator>

"By default, MatSelectionList displays radio or checkmark indicators to identify selected items. While you can hide the radio indicator for single-selection via hideSingleSelectionIndicator, this makes the component less accessible by making it harder or impossible for users to visually identify selected items."

See https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#selection

Comment: this worked for me. I am in v15.

Comment: This is good however this won't allow you to even programmatically select all options in the list..

Answer (score 1):

An interesting alternative would be to use [button toggle group](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview) with vertical orientation.

Comment: This answer is so simple yet brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Add attribute `[multiple]="false"` in `<mat-selection-list>` tag. Works for me!

*Source example: https://material.angular.io/components/list/examples#list-single-selection*

Comment: I like this answer the best. It's simple, doesn't get in the weeds with ng::deep and other styling tricks that can lead to unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Better than these options, there is a built in option called **hideSingleSelectionIndicator**. You can couple this with some css as well to default highlight.  https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#selection

```css
//this sets the background color of the selected item in the list
#my-list-id[aria-selected="true"] {
    background: rgb(232,228,228);
}
```

```html
<mat-selection-list hideSingleSelectionIndicator [multiple]="false">
    <mat-list-option id="my-list-id"> 1 </mat-list-option> 
    <mat-list-option> 2 </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Comment: best and cleanest solution

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the `multiple` directive from `<mat-select></mat-select>` the checkboxes should not be displayed.

If you want to do it using CSS then you need to add a `panelClass`, this will allow you to specify the options that you want to modify.

```
<mat-select multiple panelClass="test-class">
...
</mat-select>

::ng-deep .test-class .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
  display: none !important;
}
```

to avoid using `::ng-deep` you can place the CSS rules in the styles.css file at the root